# What if replace reflection with code generation for getting entity values in Spring Data JDBC's PersistentPropertyAccessor class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

Question: I'm currently working with Spring Data JDBC and have observed that PersistentPropertyAccessor relies on reflection for property access. I've read that reflection can impact performance, and I'd like to delve deeper into this aspect.

What are the reasons behind using reflection in PersistentPropertyAccessor for getting field values in Spring Data JDBC? Has it been considered replaced with code generation approach(f.e. MapStruct)?